# Out of bound exception while creating adjacency list with java

Tags: java, list, graph

What is issue here?
I am trying to make adjacency list with util library like list, linkedlist. But after running the code it is generating

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555) issue

```
import java.util.*;
class GraphMain{

    List<Edge> G[];
    public GraphMain(int n) {
        G=new LinkedList[n];
        for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
            G[i]=new LinkedList<Edge>();
    }
    boolean isConnected(int u,int v) {
        for(Edge i: G[u])
            if(i.v==v) return true;
        return false;
    }
    void addEdge(int u,int v) {
        G[u].add(new Edge(v)); 
    }

    void printGraph () {
        for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
        System.out.println(i+"=>"+G[i].get(i)+"\n");
    }
}
```

my tester class is:

```
public class Graph {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphMain g=new GraphMain(10);
        g.addEdge(1, 2);
        g.addEdge(2, 5);
        g.addEdge(2, 5);
        g.addEdge(8, 3);

        g.printGraph();
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception seems to be incomplete. Could you please show the rest - if any.

Comment: @blafasel I have only another class:
    class Edge{
  int v;
  public Edge(int v){
   this.v=v;
  }
 
 }

Comment: I have a good hunch about your issue - I added a detailed answer below. If it proves useful to solve your issue, could you please accept the answer by clicking on the Gray check mark next to it, making it green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is most likely connected to this printout method:

```
 void printGraph ()
{
    for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
    System.out.println(i+"=>"+G[i].get(i)+"\n");
}
```

In this method you assume that the number of node lists in G is identical or smaller than the length of each node list in G.

If G[i] node list would be shorter than i length, the get(i) would cause an index out of bounds will be thrown.

Another printout option that deals with this could be:

```
  void printGraph ()
{
    for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++) {
        for (Node node: G[i]) {
            System.out.println(i+"=>"+node+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmitBiswas, Cool. Could you please accept the answer? Just  click on the gray check mark, making it green.